# Magento2 Add dropdown option in product listing page for configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-list, category-products, dropdown-attribute

I want to change text-swatch to dropdown in category page.[image]
I want here drop down instead swatch

[image]

Comment: do you want text swatch into dropdown only for Size attribute(XL,S,M etc) or for every text swatch ?

Comment: why you cant use magento native functionality in backend to choose any attribute as "drodown","text swatch" or "visual swacth"  ?

Comment: @Shashank Kumrawat dropdown not working on category page and custom collection

Comment: @Shashank Kumrawat I want dropdown everywhere-product,category,homepage collection

Comment: have you selected them as "dropdown" in attribute properties in backend?

Comment: yes but it's only for product page.Itg remove dropdown from category page only swatches are allow on category page

Comment: are you using any custom theme ? can you share URL ?

Comment: https://themeforest.net/item/fastest-magento-2-themes-magento-212-magento-19-multipurpose-responsive-theme-10-design/16178989

Comment: @KetanBorada Have you get any solution about this query?

Comment: Hello @KetanBorada did you get the solution ? I need to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite below mentioned file in your Theme,

**vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/listing/renderer.phtml**

Comment: thanks, can you be more specific?

Comment: You'd want to edit your code that prints them one by one and make it an html [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) element

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed override the renderer.phtml as Nauman said. To add the dropdown list do the following:

1: copy **renderer.phtml** from

```
vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/listing/renderer.phtml
```

to

```
 design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Swatches/templates/product/listing/renderer.phtml
```

2: look for **"onlySwatches"** and change **false** to **true**

3: check if show in product listing is set to yes in the attribute settings in the backoffice

**Warning**: This method won't work if your product only has dropdown attributes. Magento only executes the whole option thing in the preview if there is at least one standard swatch available.

Comment: This didn't work for me